# Getting location by Wifi or Cellular Corona sdk

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk

I have a big problem with this and I'm little annoyed by how much information about this `getUserLocation()` I have found, and none of it worked. All I need is to get longtitude and latitude by cellular or wifi, nothing else, if there is any other way than `getUserLocation`, I'm OK with that.

When I run this in my phone it says **`Current location is unknown.`**

```
myMap = native.newMapView( 20, 20, 300, 220 )
function callMap()
  if(myMap ~= nil) then
    local currentLocation = myMap:getUserLocation()

    if currentLocation.errorCode ~= nil then
      native.showAlert("Jeez it doesnt work again",
                       currentLocation.errorMessage, {"OK"}) 
    else
      native.showAlert("errorCode is nil which is good","...", {"OK"}) 
    end
  else
      native.showAlert("Map is nil", "...", {"OK"})
  end
end

timer.performWithDelay( 3000, callMap )
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the problem was that my phone didn't have set up reaching position by Wifi or Cellular, thats it :D it was really easy.